# Python dataclass: can you set a default default for fields?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I want to make a dataclass base class where all the fields in subclasses are automatically Optional and default to None (if no default is provided).

The following code... almost seems to do what I want, but not quite. It errors out the same way as though I'd never written the `__init_subclass__` (i.e. complains about unfilled parameters)... perhaps because my code is running *after* the dataclass magic happens?

```
@dataclass(order=True, frozen=True)
class BaseDictKey:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(*args, **kwargs)
        # noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
        for field in cls.__dataclass_fields__.values():
            field.default = None if field.default is None else field.default
            field.type = typing.Union[field.type, NoneType]

@dataclass(order=True, frozen=True)
class ScoreDictKey(BaseDictKey):
    catalog: str  # magically becomes catalog: Optional[str] = None
    dataset: str = 'foo'  # magically becomes dataset: Optional[str] = 'foo'
```

(In case you're wondering why I want this, I have another baseclass that uses these BaseDictKeys that expects any and all fields in subclasses to be Optional. I suppose I *could* instead raise an exception if I detect something isn't an Optional, but that seems uglier.)

Is this possible in Python 3.7+?

Comment: Please describe in what way "not quite" so we don't have to guess.

Comment: Edited the original. Here's my change: It errors out the same way as though I'd never written the `__init_subclass__` (i.e. complains about unfilled parameters)... perhaps because my code is running after the dataclass magic happens?

Comment: What is this line supposed to do? `field.default = None if field.default is None else field.default`

Comment: if you look at ScoreDictKey.dataset, it should make more sense, but basically: If a default value was provided, don't overwrite it with None, but if nothing was provided, set the default to None. I didn't do `None if not field.default else field.default` because that wouldn't work for falsy-non-None default values (0, '', [], etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way with modifying class `__annotations__` field to make fields optional and setting attributes directly on class to provide default value `None`:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

import typing


@dataclass(order=True, frozen=True)
class BaseDictKey:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        for field, value in cls.__annotations__.items():
            cls.__annotations__[field] = typing.Union[value, None]
            if not hasattr(cls, field):
                setattr(cls, field, None)
        super().__init_subclass__(*args, **kwargs)


@dataclass(order=True, frozen=True)
class ScoreDictKey(BaseDictKey):
    catalog: str  # magically becomes catalog: Optional[str] = None
    dataset: str = 'foo'  # magically becomes dataset: Optional[str] = 'foo'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  # to get rid of PyCharm warning
        pass


c = ScoreDictKey()
print(c.catalog, c.dataset)  # None foo
```

Comment: Thanks! This is 90% of the way there! Works at runtime without a hitch. However... PyCharm is not smart enough to realize what has been done... it erroneously highlights the empty parenthesis and says `Parameter 'catalog_str' unfilled.` The only thing I can think of doing is manually generating the __init__ functions, which sounds like a pain.

Comment: @user3534080 to get rid of PyCharm warning I found only one way with current solution: add empty `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): pass` to subclass definition.